# PHP - Importar imágenes de un PC a la Web

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

Estoy diseñando un sistema de inventario el cual se conecta con la BD de otro sistema e importa los productos que tiene registrados.

Mi sistema está en php y el sistema del cual estoy extrayendo los datos está en VisualFoxPro.

Hasta allí está todo bien. El problema es que la tabla de productos tiene un campo llamado `Ruta_img` donde está la ruta de la imagen local (en el pc).

¿Hay alguna forma de al momento de importar los datos desde el servidor también importe las imágenes de cada producto?

Por lo que he podido investigar, tendría que convertir el pc en un servidor ftp para poder acceder a él e importar las imágenes.

También pensé en instalar Dropbox en el pc y copiar las imágenes en una carpeta dentro del dropbox para obtener las url de las mismas y así en vez de importar las imágenes al servidor utilizaría las Url's del dropbox para visualizarlas desde la web, pero tampoco tuve éxito.

¿Conocen alguna otra solución?

Comment: Podrías crear una carpeta exclusiva en tu proyecto en donde alojes las imágenes, php tiene funciones para poder subir imágenes a tu servidor, desde cualquier pc, entonces guardas las imagenes en la carpeta que crearias y en Ruta_img guardas la ruta de la imagen pero apuntando a la carpeta antes creada

Comment: Has probado a crear una carpeta en tu solución `PHP`e importar las imágenes por `FTP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el sistema esta en la misma PC (Fox y PHP), puedes por medio de codigo copiar o mover las imagenes dentro del directorio donde este al alcance tu servidor y asi php las puede tratar.

De otra manera segun entiendo, haces una consulta a las bases de datos y te traes solamente informacion por lo tanto si tienes acceso al equipo, por lo tanto puedes instalar un servidor FTP (filezilla server) que este sirviendo las carpetas donde estan las imagenes, cuando haces la peticion a la base de datos de FOX, te conectas con codigo PHP al servidor y te traes las imagenes.

De la documentacion oficial de PHP:

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Con eso lograrias lo que buscas.